# inicio de sesión en bash

Tags: bash, login

Estoy creando un script que al ejecutarlo pide un inicio de sesión y tiene la opción de crearse una usuario.

Hay un archivo externo que tiene los usuarios y contraseñas pero no sé cómo leerlo y ver si está el usuario que introdujo la persona.

Por ejemplo:

Lista de usuarios:

```
User1 
User2
```

Lista de contraseñas:

```
1234
1045
```

Lo que coloca la persona:

```
user> User3 
password> 3953
```

como no está salta error.

También puede crear una contraseña:

```
new user> User3
new password> 3953
```

En tal caso, el "User3" se coloca en la lista, así como su contraseña.

Comment: Ya existe un comando para crear usuarios y contraseñas en Unix Linux.

Comment: esque yo uso termux que es para android y simula lo que es linux y si coloco "useradd" me aparece esto:
No command 'useradd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'ssh-add' from package 'openssh'

Comment: Me da la sensación de que estás reinventando la rueda. Esto que pretendes es el fichero `/etc/passwd` / `/etc/shadow` y los comandos `useradd` / `adduser`, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui en termux no existe esos comandos por eso que estoy haciendo esto

Comment: ¿Pero funciona Bash en Termux?

Comment: si es como linux pero algunos pocos paquetes no se pueden instalar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alfinal hice esto en python:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os, getpass
lup = []
def upr():
    os.system("clear")
    with open('userslist.txt', 'r') as users:
        ucontent = users.readlines()
    for ulist in ucontent:
        usld = ulist[:-1]
        lup.append(usld)
def login1():
    os.system("clear")
    inuser = raw_input("[!v]Volver | Usuario> ")
    if inuser == '!v':
        login()
    inpw = getpass.getpass()
    if inuser+" "+inpw in lup:
        pass
    else:
        raw_input("El usuario o contraseña esta incorrecto\nVuelve a intentarlo..[Enter]")
        login1()
def singup():
    os.system("clear")
    print("Escribe el nombre del usuario nuevo")
    nusr = raw_input("Nuevo Usuario> ")
    npw = getpass.getpass()
    with open('userslist.txt', 'a') as wf:
        wf.write("\n"+nusr+" "+npw)
def login():
    os.system("clear")
    opc1 = input("Elije:\n1-Iniciar sesión\n2-Crear cuenta\nElegir> ")
    if opc1 == 1:
        login1()
    elif opc1 == 2:
        signup()
    else:
        raw_input("Eleccion invalida\nIntentalo denuevo..[Enter]")
        login()
upr()
login()
```

fue lo unico que se me ocurrio pero funciona :p